# Adapter Layout Design in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am putting a custom array adapter in my android list view, I need rounded corners for it. But adapter is getting chopped at one of the sides in both the list views.

[image]

Code for my adapter layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="2dip"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector" 
android:paddingLeft="18dip"    
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/feed_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:paddingRight="3dip"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feed_updatetime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/feed_text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip"
    android:paddingTop="3dip"
    android:text="afsdfd"
    android:textColor="#A4A4A4"
    android:textSize="8dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feed_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feed_updatetime"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip"
    android:text="afsdfd"
    android:textColor="#000000" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

code for my list view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>




<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" 
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
>



<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame1"


 >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_left"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"

    android:scrollbars="none" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:divider="#FFFFFF"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"


     >
</ListView>
<View android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="1dip"      android:background="#E4E4E4" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:divider="#FFFFFF"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"

    >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Update: After adding padding: But still no luck with bottom row.**

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't less padding and maybe a smaller font size solve the problem?

Comment: Could you be more specific? which padding and can't change the font size...

Comment: You can put a little margin, maybe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply I managed to solve the problem partially by adding some padding in my list view, however the bottom row is still not coming properly. See the question

Comment: This solution is more for the symptoms than the actual issue, but you could always set clipChildren="false" and clipToPadding="false" on the containers... The better approach would be to fix your layouts.

Comment: and By containers you mean my listview right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `paddingBottom="5dp"` in both listviews. That will make that empty space at the bottom disappear.